# Unable to find type relating to import in Yesod Import.hs

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have put in Import.hs

`import qualified Database.Esqueleto  as E`

But in my Handler file where I have

`import Import`

But it couldn't find E

```
module Handler.MyProfile where

import Import


getMyProfileR :: Handler Html
getMyProfileR = do
  now <- liftIO getCurrentTime
  wordList <- (runDB $ E.select $ E.from $ \v -> do
                  where_ (v ^. VocabularyDate E.<. val now)
                  return v)
  defaultLayout $ do
    $(widgetFile "myprofile")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. It would defeat a main purpose of qualified imports: that the qualifier-prefix tells you where something comes from. If you have `E.<.` in your code, the reader wants to be able to see where it comes from!

You have two options:

- Put `import qualified Database.Esqueleto as E` directly in `Handler.MyProfile`. This is often the best solution – while it leads to somewhat unwieldy headers on top of every source file, the advantage is that one immediately sees where everything is coming from. Yes, it violates DRY, but I think in this case it's reasonable nevertheless.
- Make a dedicated “import module” for esqueleto stuff. And, if necessary, for any other import-qualifier prefix you have.

  ```
  module Import.Esqueleto where -- package-local, hidden module
  import Database.Esqueleto
  import Database.Esqueleto....

  module Handler.MyProfile where
  import qualified Import.Esqueleto as E
  ```